# How do I get a value of a nested <span>using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to fetch Span value from below code sample.

```
<ul style="list-style:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
  <li scriptclass="SharePointFileAttachmentContainer" class="a3_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0" id="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0_V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI124" formid="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0" originalid="V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI124" viewdatanode="38">
    <span style="" onmouseover="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOver(this, event);" onmouseout="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOut(this, event);">
      <span id="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0_V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI124_SPFA1" scriptclass="SharePointFileAttachmentItem" class="b_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0 a2_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0 bh_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0" direction="ltr" viewdatanode="39" formid="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0" originalid="V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI124_SPFA1" style="margin:0px; width: 100%; display:inline-block;">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; border:none;" onclick="return (SharePointFileAttachmentItem.OnClick(this, event));" onfocus="return (SharePointFileAttachmentItem.OnFocus(this, event));" onkeypress="return (SharePointFileAttachmentItem.OnKeyPress(this, event));">
          <img title="Click here to delete the file. EAMS Masters.docx" alt="Click here to delete the file. EAMS Masters.docx" style="cursor: hand;border:none;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:1px;" src="/_layouts/inc/ipfsfileattachmentdelete.png?rev=yS8PMFXDZDJFrumpJ9CThg%3D%3D">
        </a>
        <span>EAMS Masters.docx</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li scriptclass="SharePointFileAttachmentContainer" class="a3_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0" id="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0_V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI125" formid="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0" originalid="V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI125" viewdatanode="40">
    <span style="" onmouseover="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOver(this, event);" onmouseout="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOut(this, event);">
      <span id="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0_V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI125_SPFA1" scriptclass="SharePointFileAttachmentItem" class="b_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0 a2_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0 bh_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0" direction="ltr" viewdatanode="41" formid="ctl00_m_g_92fd70a8_aeaf_433d_8f82_e1ead1630fec_FormControl0" originalid="V1_I1_SPFAC26_SPI125_SPFA1" style="margin:0px; width: 100%; display:inline-block;">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; border:none;" onclick="return (SharePointFileAttachmentItem.OnClick(this, event));" onfocus="return (SharePointFileAttachmentItem.OnFocus(this, event));" onkeypress="return (SharePointFileAttachmentItem.OnKeyPress(this, event));">
          <img title="Click here to delete the file. 123.docx" alt="Click here to delete the file. 123.docx" style="cursor: hand;border:none;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:1px;" src="/_layouts/inc/ipfsfileattachmentdelete.png?rev=yS8PMFXDZDJFrumpJ9CThg%3D%3D">
        </a>
        <span>123.docx</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

From Above code sample I want `<span>EAMS Masters.docx</span>` and   `<span>123.docx</span>` this span values.
I have multiple `<li>` like this.

So please suggest me solution in Jquery or Javascript.

Thanks,
Digambart

Comment: what is the pattern? to have .docx inside? or all span?

Comment: First and foremost, move your inline styles into classes. Then we can start helping you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it like this

```
spans = $('li[scriptclass="SharePointFileAttachmentContainer"]').find('span[id^="ctl00_m"]').find('span');
console.log( spans );
```

the breakdown (good for studying)

1. li tags with attribute of scriptclass
2. span with ids that begins with ctl00_m
3. finally find the span inside it.

if you want to loop through each spans found:

```
spans.each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

Working sample
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/HdMTH/

Answer (score 2):

If you want each `li`'s 3rd `span`'s content:

```
var i=1;
$('ul li').each(function(){
    var span_val=$(this).find('span span span').text();
    //code for doing something with span_val
});
```

working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/s3C2X/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySpans = $("li span span span");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
var spans = $('li').map(function(){
       return $(this).find('a').next('span');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code.

```
$('li').each(function(){
   $(this).find('span span:last').css('border','1px solid red'); 
});
```

in above code it will get the first `span` inside `li` and inside that `span` it will get last `span` so you will have your `span` as result.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gpjp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Far more elegant solution:

```
$('li span:nth-child(3)')
```

Check out [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('li.a3_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0').find('span span span').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kT5TU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've class `a3_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0` for `li`and a single `a` anchor tag.  You can simple have

```
   $('.a3_KcMvdcLcp51gEaVY_0 a').next('span').text();
```

check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bA7Su/)